# Change href url to # tag in parent li menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change `href` link tag to `#` through jquery.
When I click on `below html about link` the `#` tag show and link doesn't go to `about.html`

**HTML**

```
<div id="access">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="parent-menu-item"><a href="about.html">about</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="list1.html">list 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="list2.html">list 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="list3.html">list 3</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
        <li><a href="services.html">services</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="faqs.html">faqs</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why do you want to change the `attr`? Why not just disable the default link behavior?

Comment: thanks for replying because I am using wordpress menu and If I use custom menu of wordpress, then dropdown did not show on ipad

Answer (score 2):

Try this work fine :) This function change parent li inside href :)

```
$(function(){    
 $('.parent-menu-item').on('click',function(){
  $('#access ul .parent-menu-item > a').attr("href","#");    
 });     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try   this

```
 $(function(){    

          $('.parent-menu-item >a ').click(function(){
              $(this).prop('href','#');
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.parent-menu-item > a').prop('href', '#');
```

Answer (score 0):

here a
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/semir/D2AMj/)

```
$('.parent-menu-item   a').attr('href', '#');
```